# Rust matching and borrow checker

Tags: rust, matching, borrow-checker

I keep stumbling on a pattern in my Rust programs that always puts me at odds with the borrow-checker. Consider the following toy example:

```
use std::sync::{Arc,RwLock};

pub struct Test {
    thing: i32,
}

pub struct Test2 {
    pub test: Arc<RwLock<Test>>,
    pub those: i32,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn foo(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        Some(3)
    }
}

impl Test2 {
    pub fn bar(&mut self) {
        let mut test_writer = self.test.write().unwrap();

        match test_writer.foo() {
            Some(thing) => {
                self.add(thing);
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }

    pub fn add(&mut self, addme: i32) {
        self.those += addme;
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile because the `add` function in the `Some` arm tries to borrow self mutably, which was already borrowed immutably just above the match statement in order to open the read-write lock.

I've encountered this pattern a few times in Rust, mainly when using `RwLock`. I've also found a workaround, namely by introducing a boolean before the `match` statement and then changing the value of the boolean in the `Some` arm and then finally introducing a test on this boolean after the match statement to do whatever it is I wanted to do in the `Some` arm.

It just seems to me that that's not the way to go about it, I assume there's a more idiomatic way to do this in Rust - or solve the problem in an entirely different way - but I can't find it. If I'm not mistaken the problem has to do with lexical borrowing so `self` cannot be mutably borrowed within the arms of the match statement.

Is there an idiomatic Rust way to solve this sort of problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use directly the field `those`, for example with custom type:

```
use std::sync::{Arc,RwLock};

pub struct Those(i32);

impl Those {
    fn get(&self) -> i32 {
        self.0
    }

    fn add(&mut self, n: i32) {
        self.0 += n;
    }
}

pub struct Test {
    thing: Those,
}

pub struct Test2 {
    pub test: Arc<RwLock<Test>>,
    pub those: Those,
}

impl Test {
    pub fn foo(&self) -> Option<Those> {
        Some(Those(3))
    }
}

impl Test2 {
    pub fn bar(&mut self) {
        let mut test_writer = self.test.write().unwrap();

        match test_writer.foo() {
            Some(thing) => {
                // call a method add directly on your type to get around the borrow checker
                self.those.add(thing.get());
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to end borrow of a part of `self`, before mutating `self`

```
pub fn bar1(&mut self) {
    let foo = self.test.write().unwrap().foo();
    match foo {
        Some(thing) => {
            self.add(thing);
        },
        None => {}
    }
}
```

or directly mutate non borrowed part of `self`

```
pub fn bar2(&mut self) {
    let test_writer = self.test.write().unwrap();

    match test_writer.foo() {
        Some(thing) => {
            self.those += thing;
        },
        None => {}
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks red75prime. I'm going to accept Boiethios' answer as the correct one because it seems to me that he answered the "idiomatic" part. But in my code I will be using a variant of your first suggestion =)

Comment: @Vincent The solution you must use depends on the complexity of your code. If it is really complex, make everything to minimize the number of borrows that are not needed; otherwise you will fight the borrow checker sooner or later.